# I have a Redmi 4 phone , what are possible reasons for internet issues in it?

Tags: internet, redmi, reliance-lyf

There are some locations where internet in my Redmi 4 phone works very fast and every time.
But there are some locations (like the place currently i am living) where it shows full network but most of the times internet stops (becomes very slow , like just keeps buffering and never loads even a simple web page). During late night it runs without any hassle at same location.
Now at same location , when i use some one else phone (LYF) , internet works throughout the day .It becomes sometime slow but then also is able to load 360p video on you tube.

Problem is not in sim card.

Any possible reasons and solution for this.

Comment: Are the Redmi and LYF using the same carrier? If not probably the Redmi carrier is loaded during peak hours and bandwidth throttled

Comment: @beeshyams yes same carriers